# Unable to install will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I tried installing will_paginate gem in rails but it somehow not working in mine. I am unable to start my rails server.

> Bundler::GemNotFound: Your bundle is locked to will_paginate (3.1.5),
>   but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in
>   your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of
>   will_paginate (3.1.5) has removed it. You'll need to update your
>   bundle to a different version of will_paginate (3.1.5) that hasn't
>   been removed in order to install.

Comment: Is this the error you get when running `bundle install` or when starting the Rails server? If you haven't run `bundle install`, make sure to do that. If that runs successfully but you're still having trouble, please edit the post to include your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

update your gem `will_paginate` with `bundle update`

```
bundle update will_paginate
```

This replaces the version locked in your `Gemfile.lock` with the latest version

[more detail on bundle_update_documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-update.1.html)

Comment: The latest version [available at Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/will_paginate) is the version that the error message is saying the bundle is locked to, so I think `bundle update` probably won't help. There's something weirder going on here, I think.